# Ubuntu not showing setup/install menu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I dual booted windows and ubuntu and when i ran ubuntu for the first time ubuntu is telling me to log in, when i did not even set up my ubuntu.

What it looks like:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Comment: If you see this when booting from the live CD/DVD/USB drive, simply enter an empty password.

Comment: Not working... I installed ubuntu ages ago and then wiped hard drive. Now i dont get the installation screen on my pc when booting from cd, but i need to.

Comment: The live CD is a complete working Ubuntu system with a user account `ubuntu` with empty password. Just log in as that user by entering the empty password (i.e. enter nothing, just hit enter) and then after successful login the installation wizard should start. If not, there should be a desktop shortcut to it or you can find it in the launcher and dash.

Comment: @ByteCommander Apparently, after i run it, my screen just goes black for a minute or two and goes back to login page.

Comment: Looks like your installation image is damaged. Verify the hash sum of the iso file you downloaded and redownload it if they do not match. Write it to the DVD or USB drive again anyway. Then try to install Ubuntu again from the fresh medium.

Comment: @Bytecommander Thanks for your time dude, i figured out. I had to unplug my second monitor for some reason.

Comment: You could post that as answer to your own question and accept it later after the 2 days delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unplugged my second monitor and it worked perfectly. After installing I downloaded proper gtx 970 drivers, rebooted and both monitors worked.